# Keep toggle hide/show after refresh page

Tags: javascript, php

i don't know how to keep the toggle bar as it is after refresh. If the user hide the toggle bar, after page change(refresh), keep it hide.. i have this code for hide or show toggle.

```
$('.fa-bars').click(function () {

    if ($('#sidebar > ul').is(":visible") === true) {
        $('#main-content').css({
            'margin-left': '0px'
        });
        $('#sidebar').css({
            'margin-left': '-210px'
        });
        $('#sidebar > ul').hide();
        $("#container").addClass("sidebar-closed");
    } else {
        $('#main-content').css({
            'margin-left': '210px'
        });
        $('#sidebar > ul').show();
        $('#sidebar').css({
            'margin-left': '0'
        });
        $("#container").removeClass("sidebar-closed");
    }
});
```

Can someone help me? I use laravel framework.

Comment: You can use use localStorage to store what is open what is hidden and when the page is loaded read the values and apply toggle accordingly

Comment: @Bharat ok so with localStorage, i will go to read some documentations.. i dont know for now hot to use localStorage. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+bootstrap+keep+toggle+after+reload+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.